# How to flatten a 1-2-3 tree into a list?

Tags: list, recursion, tree, prolog, flatten

I'm working on a function that converts a tree into a list of integers. My issue is, I can append to the list when I only have to add one or two integers. But I can't seem to be able to append three integers without getting this:

`[[2], 3, 4]`, when I should be getting `[2, 3, 4]`.

I know that the issue stems from this statement

```
append([Temp1 | Temp2] , Temp3, L)
```

Where Temp1, Temp2, and Temp3 are the integers I'd like to add. L is the main list that contains all integers from the tree so far.

---

I tried having two append statements, but that returns a `false` boolean instead of `[2, 3, 4]`. I tried moving around the `[ | ]` but I don't think I know enough about them to have made a difference.

The append/3 page also only goes up to concatenating two lists into one. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

---

Edit: my code is as below, and I added my test example.

```
chopTree(leaf(_), []).
chopTree(node1(Leaf, Node), L) :- 
    chopTree(Node, Temp), 
    append([], [Leaf | Temp], L).
chopTree(node2(Leaf, Node1, Node2), L) :- 
    chopTree(Node1, Temp1), 
    chopTree(Node2, Temp2), 
    append(Temp1, [Leaf | Temp2], L).
chopTree(node3(_, Node1, Node2, Node3), L) :- 
    chopTree(Node1, Temp1), 
    chopTree(Node2, Temp2), 
    chopTree(Node3, Temp3), 
    append([Temp1 | Temp2] , Temp3, L).

query(E) :- 
    chopTree(node3(1, 
                   node1(2, leaf(1)), 
                   node2(3, leaf(1), leaf(1)), 
                   node1(4, leaf(1))), 
             E).
```

Comment: your code is...? do include both predicate definition and a query.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it'd be a more general question. I added my code, along with the query I used.

Comment: Why not simply write `L = [Temp1, Temp2, Temp3]` ? Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using `=`, it's a limitation my professor put in place.

Comment: and what is the desired output for the query as shown? Is it `[2,3,4]`?

Comment: @WillNess Yeah, [2, 3, 4] while I'm getting [[2], 3, 4] from my code sample.

Comment: @AndrewRaleigh I've restored the version with the code, because without the code your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your naming is off. The variable looks better called "Label". Then, `node3` should probably have *two* of them:

```erlang
chopTree(leaf(_), []).
chopTree(node1(Label, Node), L) :- 
    chopTree(Node, Temp), 
    % append([], [Label | Temp], L).
    L = [Label | Temp].
chopTree(node2(Label, Node1, Node2), L) :- 
    chopTree(Node1, Temp1), 
    chopTree(Node2, Temp2), 
    append(Temp1, [Label | Temp2], L).
chopTree(node3(Label1, Label2, Node1, Node2, Node3), L) :- 
    chopTree(Node1, Temp1), 
    chopTree(Node2, Temp2), 
    chopTree(Node3, Temp3), 
    append(Temp1, [Label1 | Temp2] , L1),
    append(L1, [Label2 | Temp3], L).
```

Perhaps `node1` shouldn't have any labels in it, too. Anyway, as you can see, we just call `append` twice, or however many times we need, to build the result list piece by piece.

Answer (score 1):

When relating trees to lists, checkout **DCG notation**: DCGs let you *avoid* `append/3` entirely, making your code simpler and at the same time often improve its termination properties.

For example:

```
tree_list(leaf(Leaf)) --> [Leaf].
tree_list(node1(Leaf, Node)) -->
        [Leaf],
        tree_list(Node).
tree_list(node2(Leaf, Node1, Node2)) -->
        tree_list(Node1),
        [Leaf],
        tree_list(Node2).
tree_list(node3(_, Node1, Node2, Node3)) -->
        tree_list(Node1),
        tree_list(Node2),
        tree_list(Node3).
```

Sample query and answer:

```
?- phrase(tree_list(node3(1,
                     node1(2, leaf(1)),
                     node2(3, leaf(1), leaf(1)),
                     node1(4, leaf(1)))), Ls).
Ls = [2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1].
```

You can easily adapt this to other desired orders, by simply moving the terminals and nonterminals within the DCG bodies.

Note that all the auxiliary variables are *gone* entirely!